# Could someone help me transcribe a Pali chant?

Tags: pali-language, chant

I'm working on the subtitles for a YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxKbO4bLDQM) and could use some help transcribing the chant at the beginning. I suppose it's one of the relatively common ones? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Pali : Namo tassa bhagavato arahato sammā-sambuddhassa.
>
> English : Homage to the Blessed One, the Worthy One, the Rightly Self-awakened
>   One.

If you are interested in this chanting, you should read [The Divine Mantra](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/lee/divinemantra.html).

Comment: Thanks, I got the "namo tassa" section but can't figure out the second part of the blessing which starts about 15 seconds into the video.